# SSH id_rsa.pub asking for passphrase when none given for keypair

Tags: ssh

I am trying to set up a new user on my Ubuntu Cloud server and i am having some issues with the SSH keypair.

Created the keypair:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Added the key to authorized_keys:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

and copied the key to another server to test a login.

This is the debug from my attempted ssh session.

```
liam@development ~/android/system $ ssh -vv -i ~/si_id_rsa.pub simon@cloud.com
OpenSSH_5.5p1-lpk, OpenSSL 0.9.8n 24 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to cloud.com [192.168.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/liam/si_id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: identity file /home/liam/si_id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 133/256
debug2: bits set: 495/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'cloud.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/liam/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug2: bits set: 513/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/liam/si_id_rsa.pub (0x673430)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/liam/si_id_rsa.pub
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 7c:cd:e3:0c:90:8a:ff:65:e1:39:54:46:03:c8:12:fc
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/liam/si_id_rsa.pub':
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

In case I had made some sort of error in creating the key I tried the process again ensuring I did not enter a passphrase.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or where to find some more info on what I am attempting to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be using the `-i` flag incorrectly, leading `ssh` to try to read your public key as a private key.  From [the OpenSSH `ssh(1)` manual page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1):

```
-i identity_file
        Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public
        key authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for
        protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa and
        ~/.ssh/id_rsa for protocol version 2.  Identity files may also be
        specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.  It is
        possible to have multiple -i options (and multiple identities
        specified in configuration files).  ssh will also try to load
        certificate information from the filename obtained by appending
        -cert.pub to identity filenames.
```

`id_rsa` is the identity file, which contains your private key, and should be kept secret and can be passphrase-protected.  `id_rsa.pub` is the public key, which you should append to `authorized_keys` on the systems you wish to use.

Try `-i ~/si_id_rsa` instead.

Comment: I see, i may have got confused. If i generate an ssh keypair for a user i need to add that key their autorized_keys and give them which key to remote login. `id_rsa` or `id_rsa.pub`?

Comment: I answered your question in my edit.